# Calculating duration per user per location user of Wi-Fi timeseries logs

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, indoor-positioning-system

I have a Wi-Fi log dataset that shows users interacting with Wireless access points (AP). I was able to generate new column named floor that shows which floor the APs are on, giving a very rough estimation of user position in the building.

Here is a simplified sample of the data set:

| ID | _user | vlan_role | Floor | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:21:49-06:00 |
| 2 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:21:49-06:00 |
| 3 | ccc | Student | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:22:57-06:00 |
| 4 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:25:21-06:00 |
| 5 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:25:21-06:00 |
| 6 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:25:26-06:00 |
| 7 | aaa | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:26:13-06:00 |
| 8 | aaa | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:26:13-06:00 |
| 9 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:26:57-06:00 |
| 10 | ccc | Student | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:26:57-06:00 |
| 12 | bbb | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:23:22-06:00 |
| 13 | bbb | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:23:22-06:00 |
| 14 | ccc | Student | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:23:44-06:00 |
| 16 | ccc | Student | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:23:49-06:00 |
| 17 | aaa | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:43:19-06:00 |
| 18 | ccc | Student | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:43:19-06:00 |
| 19 | bbb | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:43:51-06:00 |
| 20 | aaa | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:56:27-06:00 |
| 21 | aaa | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:56:27-06:00 |
| 22 | aaa | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:56:29-06:00 |
| 23 | aaa | Staff | 6 | 2022-01-03 08:56:31-06:00 |
| 24 | bbb | Staff | 6 | 2022-01-03 08:56:32-06:00 |
| 25 | bbb | Staff | 6 | 2022-01-03 09:08:16-06:00 |
| 28 | aaa | Staff | 6 | 2022-01-03 09:08:39-06:00 |
| 29 | ccc | Student | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:08:52-06:00 |
| 31 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:08:57-06:00 |
| 32 | aaa | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:10:22-06:00 |

My end goal is to generate a duration for each user at at each floor.
After some research I put this together:

```py
df["duration"] = df.groupby("Floor")["DateTime"].transform(lambda x: np.ptp(x.to_numpy()))
```

which will calculate the duration of each floor, but it doesn't account for users or break off when changing floors. Rather it just presents a total time for each floor (shown below).

| ID | _user | vlan_role | Floor | DateTime | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:21:49-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 2 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:21:49-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 3 | ccc | Student | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:22:57-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 4 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:25:21-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 5 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:25:21-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 6 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:25:26-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 7 | aaa | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:26:13-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 8 | aaa | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:26:13-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 9 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:26:57-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 10 | ccc | Student | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:26:57-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 12 | bbb | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:23:22-06:00 | 0 days 00:33:07 |
| 13 | bbb | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:23:22-06:00 | 0 days 00:33:07 |
| 14 | ccc | Student | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:23:44-06:00 | 0 days 00:33:07 |
| 16 | ccc | Student | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:23:49-06:00 | 0 days 00:33:07 |
| 17 | aaa | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:43:19-06:00 | 0 days 00:33:07 |
| 18 | ccc | Student | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:43:19-06:00 | 0 days 00:33:07 |
| 19 | bbb | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:43:51-06:00 | 0 days 00:33:07 |
| 20 | aaa | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:56:27-06:00 | 0 days 00:33:07 |
| 21 | aaa | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:56:27-06:00 | 0 days 00:33:07 |
| 22 | aaa | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:56:29-06:00 | 0 days 00:33:07 |
| 23 | aaa | Staff | 6 | 2022-01-03 08:56:31-06:00 | 0 days 00:12:08 |
| 24 | bbb | Staff | 6 | 2022-01-03 08:56:32-06:00 | 0 days 00:12:08 |
| 25 | bbb | Staff | 6 | 2022-01-03 09:08:16-06:00 | 0 days 00:12:08 |
| 28 | aaa | Staff | 6 | 2022-01-03 09:08:39-06:00 | 0 days 00:12:08 |
| 29 | ccc | Student | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:08:52-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 31 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:08:57-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |
| 32 | aaa | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:10:22-06:00 | 0 days 01:48:33 |

Since the Wi-fi devices are constantly interacting with the APs the raw data has a bunch of duplicates. For instance in the table above, User "aaa" interacts with a 1st floor AP three times before moving to the 2nd floor at ID 17. So ideally what I am trying to do is identify the new  change in floor value (ID 17) and subtract that from the old change in floor value (ID 1)... for each user. Below is an example of my expected output that I manually calculated. Duplicates are removed and a floor duration is added.

|  | oldID | newID | user | role | Floor | DateTime | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 1 | aaa | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:21:49-06:00 | 1:21:30 |
|  | 2 | 2 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:21:49-06:00 | 1:01:33 |
|  | 3 | 3 | ccc | Student | 1 | 2022-01-03 07:22:57-06:00 | 1:00:47 |
|  | 12 | 4 | bbb | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:23:22-06:00 | 0:33:10 |
|  | 14 | 5 | ccc | Student | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:23:44-06:00 | 0:48:08 |
|  | 17 | 6 | aaa | Staff | 2 | 2022-01-03 08:43:19-06:00 | 0:13:12 |
|  | 23 | 7 | aaa | Staff | 6 | 2022-01-03 08:56:31-06:00 | 0:13:51 |
|  | 24 | 8 | bbb | Staff | 6 | 2022-01-03 08:56:32-06:00 | 0:12:25 |
|  | 29 | 9 | ccc | Student | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:08:52-06:00 |  |
|  | 31 | 10 | bbb | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:08:57-06:00 |  |
|  | 32 | 11 | aaa | Staff | 1 | 2022-01-03 09:10:22-06:00 |  |

Comment: `My end goal is to generate a duration for each user at at each floor.` Why not group by both user and floor, then? e.g. change `df.groupby("Floor")` to `df.groupby(["_user", "Floor"])`.

Comment: @NickODell Yes that does get me a bit further, thanks. `df.groupby(["_user", "Floor"])` returns the total amount of time each user spent on each floor. Although, I would like to get a duration of each visit to each floor. so if a user went from the 1st to the 2nd and back to the 1st, those would all be separate durations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like there are a few problems with the data set that we'll need to resolve before getting good information:

- There are duplicate values (ie - ID 7 and 8 have the same timestamp)
- The user can interact with a floor more than once before moving

The first one can be cleaned up by running `df.drop_duplicates()` to get rid of a user interacting multiple times, which cleans up the data.

The second one is a bit more complicated - in addition to a user interacting with a floor multiple times, we also have the edge case of the end of data where a user doesn't switch the floor at the end of the data set (which it looks like you want no data for that based on your manual calculation).

For this, I recommend using `DataFrame.iterrows`, a generator that yields both the index and row (as a Series).

As you loop through the rows, you could calculate the data series and store the data in a temporary variable. I'd use a dictionary because you can be very verbose about what you're storing, like this:

```
# Pseudo code of what that data would look like
calculated_data = { 
    'aaa': {
        'last_floor':1, 
        'last_time':'2022-01-03 07:21:49-06:00'
    }
}
```

As you iterate through your dataframe, check each row against the calculated_data dict to see if the user changed floors - if they did change floors, take the difference from the last_time against the new time. This might look something like:

```
### Pseudo code
# final_data will store the output calculations
final_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['user', 'role','Floor','DateTime','Duration'])

for index, row in df.iterrows(): # df is your raw data
    # Check to see if user exists in dict - if not, add
    if (row['user'] not in calculated_data):
        calculated_data[row['user']] = {'last_floor':row['Floor'],'last_time':row['DateTime']}

    # User moved up a floor - calculate the difference and save
    elif (row['Floor'] != calculated_data[row['user']]['last_floor']):
        duration = row['DateTime'] - calculated_data[row['user']]['last_time']
        final_data.loc[len(final_data)] = [row['user'],row['role'],calculated_data[row['user']]['last_floor'],calculated_data[row['user']]['last_time'],duration
        # Update the dict with the latest floor data
        calculated_data[row['user']] = {'last_floor':row['Floor'],'last_time':row['DateTime']}
```

After that piece of code runs, you'd just want a cleanup at the end where you iterate through the dictionary to include the last set of data of floors that will have no duration and add to the final data frame (I'm referencing the last few lines of your manual calculation).

The above code snippet could be cleaned up a bit more to make it more readable, but this is the general gist - hope it helps!

EDIT:

After proofreading, I made a huge assumption that **your DataTime column is sorted**. If you're going to use my suggestion, make sure your data is sorted!

Comment: Regarding the sorted assumption: you can also enforce the assumption with `df = df.sort_values('Datetime')`